# MySQL Closest Match Two Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a database with several hundred thousand latitude/longitude. I am trying to match a latitude/longitude to the closest point. I have been using the haversine formula however it is  slow. Because I have a high density of data I would prefer to match the closest to the latitude and longitude columns. Currently I have this:

```
SELECT `ward`, ACOS(
      COS(RADIANS( `staging_gps_names`.latitude ))
    * COS(RADIANS( 51.5189698 ))
    * COS(RADIANS( `staging_gps_names`.longitude ) - RADIANS(  -0.1265003 ))
    + SIN(RADIANS( `staging_gps_names`.latitude ))
    * SIN(RADIANS( 51.5189698 ))
       )*3958.82 AS distance_miles
FROM `staging_gps_names` 
WHERE `staging_gps_names`.latitude BETWEEN 51.52 AND 51.50
ORDER BY distance_miles ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Althought ideally as mentioned above a match on the two columns would make more sense considering the density of latitude/longitudes I have, where haversine distance differences is neglible

Comment: `MIN()` will generally be much faster than `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`

Comment: Using min(**haversine formula**) seems to give me the incorrect result

Comment: Do you have an index on latitude? Does this take a long time : `SELECT ward, latitude, longitude FROM staging_gps_names WHERE latitude BETWEEN 51.52 AND 51.50 ORDER BY distance_miles ASC LIMIT 1`?